# Fineuploader in angular directive with no jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fine-uploader

So I am trying to use fine-uploader with an AngularJS directive but without depending on jQuery. I'm trying to decrease the foot print for my mobile web app so I'm looking to eliminate the jQuery dependency. Is there any other way to initialise the fineUploader module on the given/injected element in the directive?

I have a nodeJS backend which interfaces with the s3 sdk.

```
function bindToRenderedTemplate($compile, $scope, element) {
    $compile(element.contents())($scope);

}

angular.module("myApp")
    .directive("fineUploaderS3", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "ECMA",
            controller: 'FaceCardEditCtrl',
            replace: true,
            link: function($scope, element, $compile) {

                $scope.uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
                    element: element[0],
                    request: {
                        // REQUIRED: We are using a custom domain
                        // for our S3 bucket, in this case.  You can
                        // use any valid URL that poidddnts to your bucket.
                        endpoint: "my.s3.endpoint",

                        // REQUIRED: The AWS public key for the client-side user
                        // we provisioned.
                        accessKey: "MYACCESSKEY"
                    },
                    objectProperties: {
                        acl: "my-acl-property"
                    },
                    template: "qq-template-bootstrap",

                    signature: {
                        endpoint: "/s3handler"

                    },
                    scaling: {
                        sendOriginal: false,
                        sizes: [
                            {name: "small", maxSize: 200}
                        ]
                    },

                    uploadSuccess: {
                        endpoint: "/s3/uploadSuccessful"
                    },

                    // USUALLY REQUIRED: Blank file on the same domain
                    // as this page, for IE9 and older support.
                    iframeSupport: {
                        localBlankPagePath: "success.html"
                    },
                    validation: {
                        allowedExtensions: ["gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"],
                        acceptFiles: "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png",
                        itemLimit: 1,
                        sizeLimit: 1000000
                    },

                    thumbnails: {
                        placeholders: {
                            notAvailablePath: "assets/placeholders/not_available-generic.png",
                            waitingPath: "assets/placeholders/waiting-generic.png"
                        }
                    }
                });

                bindToRenderedTemplate($compile, $scope, element);

            }
        }
    });
```

The error I get when the page loads is this:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at bindToRenderedTemplate (http://localhost:9000/scripts/directives/fineUploaderDirective.js:4:5)
    at link (http://localhost:9000/scripts/directives/fineUploaderDirective.js:70:17)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6579:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5986:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5989:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5989:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6573:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5986:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5891:30)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2805:9 <div class="uploader" fine-uploader-s3="" ng-click="uploadImage()">
```

and this occurs in the line:
    $compile(element.contents())($scope);
in the **bindToRenderedTemplate** function

```
function bindToRenderedTemplate($compile, $scope, element) {
    $compile(element.contents())($scope);
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in that you are trying to inject the **$compile** at the wrong place:

```
            link: function($scope, element, $compile) {
```

this way the thing in the $compile variable will actually be an object holding the attributes on the element. See more at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, under the **Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM** section

The corrected version would be something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.directive("fineUploaderS3", function($compile) {
    return {
        ...
        link: function($scope, element) {
            ...
            bindToRenderedTemplate($compile, $scope, element);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the $compile variable has been moved from the function in the line 5 to the function in the line 2.

Answer (score -3):

Hi Irukavina thanks for the tip

I've actually managed to fix the problem. In my directive I was specifying 'element' without the '$' prefix. When I included this all things worked as expected :) But your tip also led me in the right direction.

Modified code:

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .directive("fineUploaderS3", function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "ECMA",
            controller: 'FaceCardEditCtrl',
            replace: true,
            link: function($scope, $element) {


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should add the controller code from FaceCardEditCtrl. Also, this ng-click directive won't call the code on the directive's controller, but on the containing controller. 

One of the approaches would be to add a click listener in the link function. 

Another (better by my standards) would to be add a template to your directive, and a ng-click directive inside the template.

Comment: Hi all, apologies, I have modified this post and have changed it into an answer.

Comment: Why didn't you just accept @irukavina's answer?  Your code in this "answer" is mostly just a copy and paste of his answer.  Also, this was the solution I referred to in the Fine Uploader issue tracker as well.

Comment: The thing that got me working was the '$' prefix in element which I didn't have previously, which was not mentioned in your solution or irukavina's. If other people have the same problem and forget the '$' prefix her answer was not the total solution, hence why I accepted mine instead and also upvoted hers. Regardless, if an issue, I've just accepted irukavina's as the answer. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: The `$` prefix is not necessary for the `element` parameter.

Comment: Like I said. It didn't work without the $. When I included that it worked. I just tested that right now. Feel free to ignore this if you don't agree. This is what worked for me.